# Condition checking for IF and WHILE loops while executing the statements of the loop

Tags: pseudocode

Considering following two loops :

```
if condition 1: 
   Statement1;
   Statement2;
   Statement3;

While condition2:
   Statement1;
   Statement2;
   Statement3;
```

Now for IF loop; does  condition1 is checked after executing each statement (statement1, statement2, statement3) or only after executing statement3?

Same question for While loop; Does condition2  is checked after executing each statement (statement1, statement2, statement3) or only after executing statement3?

(Statement1, statement2, and statement3 could manipulate the conditions)

Comment: There is no such thing as an if loop.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to end statements with a `;` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 1
while x==1:
    x = 2
    print(x)
    x = 3
    print(x)

if x == 3:
    x = 4
    print(x)
    x = 5
    print(x)

'''
output:
2
3
4
5

No conditions were checked
 before the statements inside the 
 block were finished
'''
```

And as stated in the comments, `if` is not a loop, and its condition is only checked once at the start. `while` is checked every time after it cycles through the indented part